# Rails get data from child table in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three tables like

1. users
2. companies
3. posts

users structure

```
user_id | f_name | l_name |
---------------------------
  1     |   abc  |  xyz   |
---------------------------
#Model User
has_many :companies
```

companies

```
company_id  |  user_id |  company_name  |
-----------------------------------------
     1      |    1     |      otto      |
-----------------------------------------
#Model Company
belongs_to :user
has_many :posts, :foreign_key => :company_id
```

posts

```
post_id  |  company_id  |  post_title  |
----------------------------------------
   1     |      1       |    helo mart |
----------------------------------------
#Model Post
belongs_to :company
```

I need view post from posts table which is created by user having `user_id 1` and whose company_id is 1.

I don't know how much did it mean, because I'm newbie on ruby on rails.

Comment: Explain what you want to achieve ?

Comment: I want view data from post table which created by `user_id 1` & `company_id 1`

Comment: thats simple : `User.find(1).companies.find(1).posts`

Comment: For example user created 10 companies, created 100 posts under 10 companies then ?

Comment: if you want all posts user created for 10 companies then `posts = [];  User.find(1).companies.map{|c| posts << c.posts }`

Comment: There are many ways. You should first read the official guides about associations between models/tables. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have already fetched company id of the user, the query for question would go like this:

```
@posts = User.find(1).companies.find(1).posts
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming company ids are unique (rather than unique per user), you don't need to look the user up at all.

```
posts = Company.find(1).posts
```